# How to Prove / Disprove statements about limits

Tags: calculus

I don't need explicit answers, but rather an idea of where to go.

The question is:

Given a graph of a function, which statements are true and which are false?

[image]

> a) $$\lim\limits_{x \to -1^+} f(x)=1$$
>
> b) $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=0$$
>
> c) $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=1$$
>
> d) $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(x)= \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$$
>
> e) $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) $$

exists

And other similar problems. I know that that they're true/false already, but I don't know how to prove that. We don't use delta-epsilon proofs in my class.

We're not required to do full proofs, but need some 'exposition' on why it's true/false, counterexamples okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using epsilon-delta, I think the rigor is somewhat vague, but of course the methods are still acceptable. However, what one generally does is proving that the limit does not exist (or is not equal to given limit) by showing that there exist two different paths which gives separate limits. One can show that limits are unique, so this means that the limit cannot exist. In the one-dimensional case, you can only go horizontally (i.e. $\to +$ or $\to -$). In two-dimensional, there are many choices, just as an example take $\lim_{x,y \to 0} xy/(x^2+y^2)$. Along the $x$- or $y$-axis, the limit is $0$, just put $x=0$ or $y=0$. However along $y= y(x) := x$, the limit is $1/2$, thus the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing $L_+=\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)$ using just the graph, put a finger somewhere on the graph near $c$ and to its right. Imagine there is a vertical dotted line at $x=c,$ and also move the finger, keeping it on the graph, so it's $x$ coordinate is moving towards $c$ (so this means the finger moves leftwards on the graph). Wherever that moving finger would hit that dotted line the $y$ coordinate there would be the value of $L_+.$ A similar thing is done for $L_-=\lim_{x \to c^-}f(x)$ only this time you start to the left of $c$ and are moving to the right.

If you see limit as $x \to c$ without a $+$ or $-$ superscript on the $c$ you do both sides and only if they match does that "two sided" limit exist. Note that some texts allow one to drop the +/- for a limit as x goes to a point where $f(x)$ fails to exist on one side of $c,$ e.g. limit as $x \to 0$ of $\sqrt{x}.$